# Error in "zoo" objects using hydroTSM package

Tags: r, time, series

I am using the `hydroTSM` package to deal with hydrological time series modelling. I am trying to convert my daily rainfall data to monthly data series. The code I am using is

```
C152072P <- read.csv("C152072P.txt", sep="",header=T)
x <- C152072P
m <- daily2monthly(x, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

It is returning error as :

```
In zoo(x, dates):
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I tried to see for any duplicate values using

```
anyDuplicated(C152072P)
```

It is returning 17 as answer. I am not sure how to proceed from here. These are observed data and how do I modify these?

Comment: Neither `C152072P` nor `x` are `timeSeries` objects (class required by function `daily2monthly`).

Comment: Thank you. C1512072P is a text file of daily data of 61 years having one single data column. How do I convert it to timeseries objects?

Comment: I would recommend to read the different help pages. They exist for this purpose.